# Ubuntu 20.04 repository problem

Tags: apt, 20.04, wine, ppa, repository

I am trying to install Wine on 20.04 focal and after banging my head against the wall trying to troubleshoot dependency issues for an hour, I recognized that 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu **kinetic** InRelease' is being checked when I run sudo apt update.  Obviously the Kinetic build is not going to work on Focal and it is trying to install file versions that are newer than the most up to date for Focal.

I have checked the software updates gui, etc/apt/sources.list and etc/apt/sources.d.list/ and do not see that PPA listed anywhere.  Any ideas where this is being stored and how to remedy it?

`sudo apt update`:

```
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-3-local  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-3-local  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-3-local  Release [564 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-3-local  Release [564 B]
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                         
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                      
Hit:6 https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease                                                                                                                                                         
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                 
Hit:8 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                   
Hit:9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                                                                                                                                                  
Hit:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                              
Hit:11 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal InRelease                                                                                                                                       
Hit:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                                                                         
Hit:13 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal InRelease                                                            
Hit:14 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease                                        
Hit:15 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

output from `sudo nano etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190210)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
```

---

I browsed to /etc/apt/sources.d.list/ and ran ls -l at least 4 different times to sanity check myself and did not see the Wine repository listed, but based on @guiverc comment, I just ran `ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and sure enough there it was.

```
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jan  5 19:10 winehq-focal.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 165 Nov 14 10:28 winehq-kinetic.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 176 Jan  5 19:59 wireshark-dev-ubuntu-stable-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 144 Feb  4  2021 wireshark-dev-ubuntu-stable-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 176 Jan  5 19:59 wireshark-dev-ubuntu-stable-bionic.list.save
```

I ran `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-kinetic.sources` and readded the Focal repository and now everything looks right when I run `sudo apt update`, but installing Wine is still giving me a bunch of random dependency errors.  I will keep troubleshooting that and start a new thread if I can't figure it out.  I followed a bunch of threads when the wrong ppa was in place, so let me backtrack and see what happens.

Comment: @Nmath I understand that, but the problem is I don't know where the Kinetic repository for Wine is being added... I don't see it in sources.list or any of the files under sources.list.d/

Comment: @Nmath I wish I knew...

Comment: @guiverc since the Wine repository is not currently showing up in the sources.list file, I don't think that blowing it away is going to resolve the issue...

Comment: You've only provided parts of your sources; it's common for users to add additional items in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` which you possibly mentioned (*only you used a relative path which may also differ greatly depending on $PWD*) but also don't specify actually checking (*due to possibly typo*)